# Postfix Change subject based on recipient

Tags: email, postfix

We are using postfix as a mail relay. I am trying to change the subject of an email based on the recipient address. It looks like check_header is possibly the tool I need but I cant seem to have it filter on recipient but replace on subject.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a content filter.

The [Postfix documentation on builtin filters (which includes **header_checks**)](http://www.postfix.org/BUILTIN_FILTER_README.html) specifies:

*"Header/body checks cannot depend on the recipient of a message."*

The difference between a content-filter and a milter is that a milter happens before the queue:

[Postfix: content-filter vs. milter](https://serverfault.com/questions/88660/postfix-content-filter-vs-milter)

You can use **header_checks** to send only the recipient-bound emails to the filter in question (to spare postfix the extra work):

[How to rewrite email subject in postfix for outgoing mail if From contains specific address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/512860/how-to-rewrite-email-subject-in-postfix-for-outgoing-mail-if-from-contains-speci)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using transports and header checks.

In /etc/postfix/transport file add:

```
destination@address.com custom_transport:
```

This will enable a particular transport for the desired recipient which will then be associated with the subject changes. Replace destination@address.com with the actual address. The name custom_transport is arbitrary but all references must be to the same name.

In /etc/postfix/main.cf add:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

These lines will enable header checks and transport maps respectively.

In /etc/postfix/master.cf add:

```
custom_transport ... smtp 
  -o smtp_header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/rewrite_headers
```

Replacing ... with the rest of the smpt transport options already defined in that file.

Finally create the file /etc/postfix/rewrite_headers (the name is arbitrary but it must match the one in the line added to the master file) with the following content:

```
/^Subject:(.*)/ REPLACE Subject: Desired subject text
```

This will replace the subject with the desired one.

Reload or restart postfix.

References: http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

Comment: worked for me as described.